# Eclipse error create android app:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar

When I create a project in eclipse this error occurs:

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

I have try to do this:

1- File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose "appcompat"
2- Project-> properties->Android. In the section library "Add" and choose "appCompat"

BUT when I open File->Import I can`t find 'android-sdk'. I only see 'android'. and I don't know how to should import that(the address:android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat is available in my computer drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the compile version to the latest sdk that you have installed ie 22 or 23 and it should work.